# Fastest way to import data into Neo4j with Lucene

Tags: java, import, neo4j, lucene

I have a large dataset of about 20million `Person` nodes with a `text` field that I want to index with Lucene. What is the best way to do such a large data import in Neo4j when one of the fields require a lucene index?

1. **Cypher:** `CREATE (n:Person { pid:538, text: 'hello this is me', name: 'David' })` where `text` is preconfigured to be indexed by Lucene.
2. **API:** Iteratively nodes are created, properties are set and text is added to the Lucene index:

`Node node = graphDb.createNode(DynamicLabel.label("Person"));
node.setProperty("name","David"); node.setProperty("pid",538);
nodeIndex.add(node,"text","hello this is me");`

3. **CSV importer**: Can we use the batch importer when one of the fields require a manual lucene index? If yes, how do I go about it?

Thanks!!

Comment: This post is pretty through, did you check it? https://neo4j.com/blog/bulk-data-import-neo4j-3-0/

Comment: Thank you, that's a great resource. Only thing is, it doesn't look like neither the questions nor the answers seem to be indexed by Lucene. That's the question I'm having, whether the batch importer can index fields with Lucene.